# Installation fails due to unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I just tried to install XRDP on my in house Ubuntu Server and got the following. Not seen it before and not sure what to do.

```
knoppysdev@knoppysdigitalserver:~$ sudo apt install xrdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-154-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-151-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-151-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-151-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-154-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-154-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I an `sudo apt-get -f install` and got the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 173 not to upgrade.
16 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,928 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,227 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 611731 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic_4.4.0-154.181_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic (4.4.0-154.181) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic_4.4.0-154.181_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-154-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-154-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-154-generic_4.4.0-154.181_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Have you tried `sudo apt install -f` as suggested in output?

Comment: What was the last thing you installed (successfully or not) before this began?

Comment: @Kulfy Ive edited the question to show the output from the command.

Comment: @AlexKnopp You're running out of space on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to try is like the error message says

`apt-get -f install`

If this doesn't work, then we've got a bigger issue.

See [this excellent post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) for more information.

Comment: Ive edited the question to show the output from the command.

Comment: As others suggested, you might be running out of disk space. Run `df -h` to see the remaining disk space.

Answer (score 0):

So yes turned out boot was full. Plenty of space left on the server (2 TB).
So I looked up the following which helped me out with my desktop setup a while back.
https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2760cfc28be62a5ee10036851c654600

Thanks everyone for all your help.